# Closing one child-form closes other child-form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the following code, `Form1` opens two other `Form`s, and then closes one of them. The result is that the second child-Form gets closed as well. Why?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer { Interval = 2000 };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ShowForm3();
        (new Form2()).ShowDialog();//If this is changed to 'Show' - it doesn't get closed.
    }

    void ShowForm3()
    {
        Form3 f3 = new Form3();
        f3.Show();
        timer.Tick += (sender, e) => f3.Close();
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

`Form2` and `Form3` are default VS Forms.

(**Additionally**: This is a simple version of the original code. In the original (which is, of course, too long to post here) this doesn't happen when executed from Visual Studio (neither Debug nor Release). It only happens when installed as a clickonce application, and then - even if I just click the executable (under the AppData folder). (Perhaps there is some other piece of the code that prevents it from happening there when executed from VS but I haven't found what yet.) What could be the causing that discrepancy? Perhaps some type of optimization in clickonce that isn't done in regular Release mode?)

Comment: It is the time to open `Reflector`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I assume you mean for the last paragraph. Good idea. Thanks.

Comment: No, I can reproduce using VS itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your code to this that will work:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer { Interval = 2000 };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ShowForm3();
        (new Form2()).ShowDialog(this);
    }

    void ShowForm3()
    {
        Form3 f3 = new Form3();
        f3.Show();
        timer.Tick += (sender, e) => f3.Close();
        timer.Start();
    }
  }
```

explanation: when you didn't pass the form parent, the windows will the active window as parent using this method: [GetActiveWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646292%28VS.85%29.aspx) and what was happend is:

when call form2.showDialog() // the parent window is form 3 because the method the GetActiveWindow get the window that is showing and form1 isn't the active  or showing

when you force the parent:
when call form2.showDialog(this) // the parent window is form 1 because you defined fixed

Comment: Can you explain? this works. but why that doesn't and this does?

Comment: Run the old code without starting the timer. Break and look at what the parent of Form3 is. I suspect the parent will have been set to Form2 (as it was the topmost form when Form3 was shown).

Comment: Thanks. However a note: Though the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) agree with you - it seems that actually, the Owner is null (in my version). You can see this by adding a `MessageBox.Show(f2.Owner.Text);` in the `Tick` Handler.